# Detect if PCRE was built without the --enable-unicode-properties or --enable-utf8 configuration switches

Tags: php, utf-8, pcre

I've a PHP library that uses a number of regular expressions featuring the `\P` expressions for multibyte strings, e.g.

```
((((?:\P{M}\p{M}*)+?)|(\'[^\']*\')|(\"[^\"]*\"))!)?\$?([a-z]{1,3})\$?(\d+)
```

While this works on most builds, I've had a few reports of the regexp returning an error.

Depending on Operating platform, the error messages from PCRE are:

> Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P, \p, \U, \u, or \X at offset n

or

> Compilation failed: support for \P, \p, and \X has not been compiled at offset n

I know that I can probably test a regexp at the beginning of my code that uses `\P`, and trap for a returned error, then use that response to set a compatibility flag and provide a degraded (non UTF-8) regexp without the `\P` within the main body of my code based on that compatibility flag.

I was wondering if there was any simpler way to identify whether PCRE had been built without the `--enable-unicode-properties` or `--enable-utf8` configuration switches. PHP provides access to `PCRE_VERSION` constant, but that won't help identify whether `\P` support is enabled or not.

Comment: I wonder if `PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET` would be defined if you didn't compile with utf8 support.  Check if that constant exists (`defined('PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET');`) on the platforms that weren't compiled in.  If it doesn't have it, there's your check.  If it does, you could always parse `phpinfo()`, but that's not going to be cheap...

Comment: phpinfo() doesn't actually provide that information... I've already checked. I'll do a new PCRE build on one of my test servers and rebuild PHP against that to see if PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET is defined, that would provide a cleaner alternative to my fallback if I was able to simply test for a defined constant.

Comment: Well, since PCRE is compiled by PHP itself, shouldn't it be a configure option for PHP?  (meaning, shouldn't it appear in the `configure` line of Phpinfo)?  I could be wrong there though...

Comment: I think if PHP is using the built-in PCRE, it's built with all PCRE multibyte options enabled by default, with no extra PHP configuration settings. The problem seems to arise when PHP has been built with --with-pcre-regex=DIR pointing to a PCRE built without the multibyte options. So all I can identify from phpinfo() is that an external PCRE was used. I'd then need to check against that PCRE using something like netcoder's pcretest suggestion... not particularly clean or efficient.

Comment: @ircmaxell - Testing to see if PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET is defined appears to do the trick. Thanks

Comment: @ircmaxell Could you turn this into an answer?

Comment: @ircmaxell, the constant is called PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET_ERROR (there's also a PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR) not PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET

Comment: @matteo - Thanks, it was PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR that I ended up using after checking the PHP docs

Answer (score 3):

Other than trying it, I think the only way is to use the `pcretest` command line tool, with the `-C` option (compile-time options):

```
bash-4.1.5$ pcretest -C
   No UTF-8 support
   No Unicode properties support
   Newline sequence is LF
   \R matches all Unicode newlines
   Internal link size = 2
   POSIX malloc threshold = 10
   Default match limit = 10000000
   Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
   Match recursion uses stack
```

Comment: Won't help since PCRE is bundled with PHP (and hence can use a different compile from what's installed on the server - if it's installed on the server)...  For example, on one of my systems PCRE is version 6.6, but PHP's PCRE version is 8.02...

Comment: Sadly true, PHP can use its own PCRE, or a PCRE from the server, depending on how it was built.

Answer (score 1):

While comments suggest checking for `PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR` the PHP source http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c#141 suggests this constant is always available if PCRE is. Indeed it seems `--enable-unicode-properties` is a PCRE lib switch and is simply not exposed by PHP. The only thing I can imagine is running a simple regexp once with warning supressed...