# PHP says "PCRE is not compiled with UTF-8"

Tags: php, apache2, debian, pcre

I have a webserver with some personal websites and stuff, it's running Debian Lenny, Apache 2 and PHP 5. I always use `apt` to install stuff.

This weekend, I tried installing Ruby on Rails just for fun. I didn't get it working, but that's a problem for another time. Today I noticed that one of my websites running PunBB has stopped working. The error I get is the following:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset 0 in /home/arood/sitename/include/utf8/utf8.php on line 51 Fatal error: PCRE is not compiled with UTF-8 support in /home/arood/sitename/include/utf8/utf8.php on line 52
```

`pcretest -C` tells me I have version 8.12 installed with UTF-8 support on the server, but `phpinfo()` tells me it's using 8.02. I've found out via google that apache is using it's own version, but I can't figure out how to fix my problem.

Could somebody help me get this working again?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried asking this in PunBB's community? Maybe you could show the code line, that is causing this error? Maybe it's fixable...

Comment: The problem seems to show up when /u is used in a preg_match, `if ( preg_match('/^.{1}$/u',"ñ",$UTF8_ar) != 1 ) {` ... I guess I could code around this, but it worked before and I don't want to risk that something breaks.

Comment: Closevoting for serverfault. -- Now that's not a good workaround, but you could try `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/licpcre.so.3` in `/etc/default/apache2` if you run mod_php. Otherwise `SetEnv` for PHP-CGI versions. Not sure if either works though.

Comment: Just add that line and restart apache? Didn't work :/. Could you elaborate what you mean with `SetEnv`?

Comment: I had a similar problem recently. My solution (as suggested by folks here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509576/detect-if-pcre-was-built-without-the-enable-unicode-properties-or-enable-utf8 ) was to test for whether PCRE was built with --enable-unicode-properties or --enable-utf8 configuration, and to provide alternative expressions if it wasn't. Not sure if the solution will help your situation, but it might provide a workround.

Comment: @arood: Try with `export LD_PRELOAD=..` then and use the /etc/init.d script to restart Apache. For CGI versions with [.htaccess SetEnv LD_PRELOAD /lib/libpcre.so.3](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html#setenv). Migrate from mod_php to the fastcgi version just to test anyway.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that I'm not very good at server-stuff, but I'm happy to learn new stuff. I tried running `export LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libpcre.so.3` and restarting but it didn't help.