# Does using /u modifier in PCRE cause any problemm if unicode is not used?

Tags: php, pcre

`/u` modifier is used in PCRE when we use unicode characters like `/x{0xFF0}`.

Does it cause any problem if we have a regex like `/^\d{10}$/u` (e.g. using unicode modifier when unicode is not used in regex) ? I ask this because I get different results in localhost and production server(using `preg_match` function)

And if it doesn't cause any problem, why this modifier is not used by default?

Comment: It shouldn't cause any problem, because ASCII is a subset of utf-8; and it isn't used by default because it's more costly in terms of performance... but also because the underlying pcre may not support it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509576/detect-if-pcre-was-built-without-the-enable-unicode-properties-or-enable-utf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not cause any problems as ascii characters are part of utf-8, just gotta be careful as the "u" modifier depends on the PCRE being compiled with --enable-utf8.