# Not able to import XML data

Tags: php, docker, mediawiki, pcre

I tried to import data from XML file using the importDump utility...

```
root@aace30d9b5f3:/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.36.1# php ./maintenance/importDump.php mrwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream.xml
```

Got this error:

```
MWException from line 2108 of /var/www/html/mediawiki-1.36.1/includes/parser/Parser.php: PCRE needs to be compiled with --enable-unicode-properties in order for MediaWiki to function
```

I downloaded the source code of PCRE and run make / make install but that did not work. I am using the official docker image of mediawiki if that matters.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki

---

update:

I need to simplify what I am trying to ask...

1. Is PCRE compiled using --enable-unicode-properties in this dockerfile?

https://github.com/docker-library/php/edit/master/7.3/buster/apache/Dockerfile

2. Is that php image being used by mediawiki official repo?

https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-docker/blob/51105612d2e1168f1b0545f47951847d63fb9613/1.36/apache/Dockerfile

Comment: Adding docker tag to know if unicode support can be added in the image.

Comment: pcretest -C command shows unicode supported, but php script fails. :)

Comment: Are you sure that PHP is actually using the PCRE version that you compiled ? Run `php -r "phpinfo();"` and see if the PCRE version is the same as the one you see when running `pcretest -c`

Answer (score 0):

PHP, unfortunately, usually uses its own PCRE library (from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php): "By default, this extension is compiled using the bundled PCRE library"), as you can also see in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509576/detect-if-pcre-was-built-without-the-enable-unicode-properties-or-enable-utf).

What you need to do is *recompile PHP itself* in order to activate the PCRE changes. To do this you need to (**you can do this on a cloned machine**)

- check out the exact PHP version
- download and install the relevant source packages
- get the exact compilation options from `phpinfo()`
- change the PCRE options appropriately
- `make` (you don't need install as you're not going use PHP in the cloned machine)

The only file that you need to change now is the basic PHP binary (`/usr/bin/php`, watch out for alternatives symlinks). If you used a cloned machine with the same distro and versions, you can easily rename that one binary on the original machine and move in the new one, and it will work (I've done this dozens of times), so you'll have the option to go back at any time.

Or you can install the development packages for PCRE on the cloned machine and supply `--with-pcre-regex=` and `--with-pcre-dir=` to the compiler. The new PHP binary will now use the system PCRE, so that `pcretest -C` will now yield reliable results. I am not sure whether you need the same PCRE version on both machines (you probably need the same major version, but a minor version mismatch shouldn't be a showstopper). Be aware that updating the system PCRE library might break compatibility with PHP if for any reasons the library calls change.